# prove when $r \geq t $ then $ x^{r} \geq x^{t} $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> when $ r,t \in \mathbb{Q} , x \geq 1 $ and $ r\geq t $, prove $ x^{r} \geq x^{t} $.

i have tried so much but i can't prove it. :(

My attempt : i can derive from it that this proposition is equal to that where  $ s \in \mathbb{Q} , x \geq 1 $ then $ x^{s} \geq 1 $.
$ x^{r} - x^{t} = x^t (x^{r-t}-1) \geq 0 $. so it is proved when we can prove that where  $ s \in \mathbb{Q} , x \geq 1 $ then $ x^{s} \geq 1 $.

it's too hard to me to prove it. please help me prove it.

Comment: The appropriate proof depends on which facts about exponentiation you have available.

Comment: this question arises from the first chapter of real analysis text. so we can use the elementary facts of exponentiation such as exponentiation defined on rational numbers, but cannot use the fact about it defined on real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trivial for $s=0$, so write $s=\frac ab$, where $a,b\ge 1$ are integers, then
$$x^s=\sqrt[b]{x^a}\ge 1\iff x^a\ge 1\iff x\ge 1$$
We actually need only right to left implications, $x\ge1\implies x^a\ge1$ is a trivial property of multiplication and the other just says roots of a number $\ge1$ are again $\ge1$ (which again follows from that trivial property of multiplication since $\sqrt[b]y<1\implies y=(\sqrt[b]y)^b<1$).

Answer (score 0):

For $ x \ge 1$ we have $\ln x \ge 0$. Then
$$
r \ge t \Rightarrow \\
r \ln x \ge t \ln x \iff \ln x^r \ge \ln x^t
$$
As $\ln$ is strictly increasing ($\ln' x = 1/x > 0$) it follows
$$
 x^r \ge x^t
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $r \geq t$ then $r=t+j$ so we can rewrite the equation like this:
$$x^r \geq x^{r+j} $$

$$x^r \geq x^r \cdot x^j\rightarrow 1 \geq x^j$$
Now we know from the hypothesis that $x \geq 1$; but then we must have that $j \leq 0$
Notice that every number elevated to zero is just one ($x^0=1$) so:

$$x^0 \geq x^j$$ 
and this statement is always true. But notice that here $j \leq 0$ so if $x^j \leq x^0$ then $j \leq 0$ and viceversa; generalizing if $r\geq t$ then $x^{r} \geq x^{t}$

QED

---

You can use induction.

$1)$ Show that the propriety $x^r\geq x^t$ if $r \geq t$ holds if $r=t=0$

$2)$ Show that if the propriety $x^r\geq x^t$ holds if then should also $x^{r+1} \geq x^{t+1}$

**Demonstration**

*Hypothesis*: $x^r\geq x^t$ if $r \geq t$.

$1)$ Is trivial that $x^0 \geq x^0$ because $1 \geq 1$

$2)$ We have to show that $x^{r+1} \geq x^{t+1}$
$$x^{r+1} \geq x^{t+1}$$
$$x \cdot x^r \geq x \cdot x^t$$
$$x^r\geq x^t$$
which is true because of the hypothesis.

QED